# Getting NullPointerException whille inserting element in BST

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert element in Binary Search Tree with iterative method but i am getting NullPointerException and i am not able to figure out why this error is getting. I tried changing the loop and checking the temp but i didnt get what is happening wrong there. 
EDIT:- I have added the whole Code.

```
     import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;

  class Node {
      Node left;
      Node right;
      int data;

      Node(int data) {
          this.data = data;
          left = null;
          right = null;
      }
  }

  class Solution {

      public static void preOrder(Node root) {

          if (root == null)
              return;

          System.out.print(root.data + " ");
          preOrder(root.left);
          preOrder(root.right);

      }

      /* Node is defined as :
      class Node 
         int data;
         Node left;
         Node right;

         */

      public static Node insert(Node root, int data) {

          Node inserter = new Node(data);
          Node temp = root;
          while (true) {
              if (inserter.data <= temp.data) {
                  if (temp.left == null) {
                      temp.left = inserter;
                      break;
                  } else
                      temp = temp.left;

              } else {
                  if (temp.right == null) {
                      temp.right = inserter;
                      break;
                  } else
                      temp = temp.right;

              }
          }

          return root;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          int t = scan.nextInt();
          Node root = null;
          while (t-- > 0) {
              int data = scan.nextInt();
              root = insert(root, data);
          }
          scan.close();
          preOrder(root);
      }
  }
```

Comment: root node can be Null. Did you check it?

Comment: Where do you get the nullpointer? On which line in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit ``` if (temp.left == null) ``` at this line I am getting NullPointerException error.

Comment: It looks like you're passing a null to the first argument - `root`.You didn't post the code where you call this method so we can't really help you any further.

Comment: @Amongalen I have added the whole Code now.

Comment: I can't really believe `temp.left == null` is causing the `nullpointer`, as this would mean `temp` is null, in which case the condition in the `inserter.data <= temp.data` if condition above would already throw the `nullpointer`.

Comment: @htpvl  I uploaded whole code now please check.

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit i run it in hackerrank compiler it was showing at that point. I have uploaded whole code please check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int t = scan.nextInt();
      Node root = null;
      while (t-- > 0) {
          int data = scan.nextInt();
          root = insert(root, data);
      }
      scan.close();
      preOrder(root);
  }
```

In main method you are passing `root == null`

You need to rewrite your **insert** **method** then it will work

```
public static Node insert(Node root, int data) {

          // check if root == null then initialize root and return it
          if(root == null){ 
               return new Node(data);
          }
          //--------

          Node inserter = new Node(data);
          Node temp = root;
          while (true) {
              if (inserter.data <= temp.data) {
                  if (temp.left == null) {
                      temp.left = inserter;
                      break;
                  } else
                      temp = temp.left;

              } else {
                  if (temp.right == null) {
                      temp.right = inserter;
                      break;
                  } else
                      temp = temp.right;

              }
          }

          return root;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Got it . I added the condition when the root will be null. `if(root == null) {
                        root = inserter ;
                        return root ;
                      }`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your main method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int t = scan.nextInt();
      Node root = null;
      while (t-- > 0) {
          int data = scan.nextInt();
          root = insert(root, data);
      }
      scan.close();
      preOrder(root);
  }
```

You initialize `Node root = null`, and the first time you enter your while loop, root will still be null when passing it to the insert method: `root = insert(root, data);`

```
public static Node insert(Node root, int data) {
  Node inserter = new Node(data);
  Node temp = root;
  while (true) {
    if (inserter.data <= temp.data) {
    ...
```

So the first time you enter the insert method, temp will be set to null, giving a nullpointer on the `temp.data` in the `if (inserter.data <= temp.data)` line.

Comment: How do I fix it ? I tried but cannot get it. Sorry i am beginner in java trying to solve some problems.

Comment: Just use the new Node(int data) constructor to create a root node instead of assigning a null to it and continue whatever you are doing.

Comment: Thanks I got it , i added the condition when the root will be null. `if(root == null) {
                        root = inserter ;
                        return root ;
                      }`